# Solving $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{n+1}{n})^n $

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n = e$$

I would like to know how to solve such a limit.

Comment: It's one of the definitions of $e$

Comment: What is your definition of $e$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit of $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$ is actually the first real definition of $e$. The standard practice is to show that the sequence is bounded from above and increasing, therefore the limit exists. The limit is then named $e$.